# How to inform NSFetchedResultsController about [NSManagedObjectContext save]

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I've the following question in Objective-C. When I delete an object from my ManagedObjectContext an saved this change, how can I inform my fetchedResultsController to perform a new fetch? In my understanding it is not correct to send performFetch-Message agian.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

using this delegate methods you can make it posible

```
fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```

And set the value of the parameter cacheName to nil. it avoids crash and keeps only current data after ManagedObjectContext change

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetched results controller delegate


- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
       atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

switch(type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

UITableView *tableViews = self.tableView;

switch(type) {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableViews insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableViews deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [_delegate configureCell:[tableViews cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        [tableViews deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableViews insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
[self.tableView endUpdates];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                              animated:NO];
}
```

this code automatically update and reload when you add,delete or update the data in NSFetchedResultsController and UITableViewController

Comment: Works as long as the number of changes are small. If you get a large bulk update then this will lag the UI thread horribly...

Comment: I'm having trouble with even just 1. But it's not lag.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `postNotificaton` for which you should already have an observer set in your controller which will initiate the fetch request again.